# Attachment page gives 404 if user not logged

Tags: url-rewriting, attachments, 404-error

I am struggling on a very weird behaviour for a WP site I have developed.

My client have uploaded many photos to the media library, and tags them with some custom taxonomies I have defined.
Some of these photos are linked to posts, some are not.

My permalink scheme is /%category%/%postname%/
Here comes the strange part: some photos have their URL rewritten like

http://example.com/[category name]/[post name]/attachment/[photo name]

Others are *not* rewritten at all

http://example.com/?attachment_id=[id]

and this happen regardless of them being attached or not to a post!

But - even more strange - many of the ones which are not rewritten throw out a 404...
Last but not least, if I browse the site as a logged user the 404 is gone and I correctly see those attachment pages.
Do you guys have an explanation for this?!?

Some additional info:
- I am not checking user logged status whatsoever.
- I have tried disabling all the plugins I'm using... none of them is messing with permalinks I'd say, except for Yoast SEO maybe.
- I don't have any custom rewrite rule defined. I even tried to disable permalinks, but with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might try determining if this behavior is related to the current theme.  Try switching to a default WP theme to see if this changes the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jdm2112, but I have solved the mystery... and the reason was quite simple, but hard to spot for me: 404 images were attached to post that my client had changed to Draft status!!